# update plots on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, updates

I'm trying to update plots on a matplotlib figure
but there is something that The application crash and stop working when I try to use

```
self.plot.remove()
```

this is the full code I found on a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_AKgfSMn-E&t=1s) tutorial it was working properly with bar plotting but something is wrong with plots

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Set Matplotlib Chart Value with QLineEdit Widget')
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.input = QLineEdit()
        self.input.textChanged.connect(self.update_chart)
        layout.addWidget(self.input)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(plt.Figure(figsize=(15, 6)))
        
        # set figure background color
        self.canvas.figure.patch.set_facecolor('#303030')
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.insert_ax()

    def insert_ax(self):
        font = {
            'weight': 'normal',
            'size': 16
        }
        matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

        self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        self.ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
        self.plot = None

    def update_chart(self):
        value = self.input.text()
        try:
            value = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            value = 0

        print(value)
        x_position = [0.5]
        if self.plot:
            self.plot.remove()

        self.plot = self.ax.plot(x_position, value, c='r', marker='o', linestyle="solid",linewidth=10)

        self.canvas.draw()
        # self.canvas.flush_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # don't auto scale when drag app to a different monitor.
    # QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QWidget {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    ''')

    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

Comment: Please add the error in your question.

Comment: The application crash and stop working question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
self.plot.remove()
```

with this:

```
self.plot.clear()
```

After that it should work.

Comment: that's great now it dosen't crash and works properly but it's not removing the old plost

Comment: it's just adding new plots with the old ones still there

Comment: Glad that this answer helped you resolving the crash problem, which is the solution to this stack overflow question. Plese, mark this answer as the solution. Regarding your second question, you need to learn how Matplotlib works and where it store things. Try adding `self.ax.lines.clear()` just below `self.plot.clear()`.

Comment: marked as the solution and thankes for also answering the second one it also works properly

Comment: I'm just starting with Matplotlib I will appreciate it if you have any good references to learn from

Comment: Matplotlib gallery is a good starting point. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html